Can You Build a Propeller or Airfoil for a Higgs Field?
The Higgs field is described as a
viscous field, akin to syrup for the particles that interact with it.
That got me thinking: could a propellor, then, be constructed that generates "thrust" from the viscosity of the Higgs field?
This would be a propellentless (no rocket exhaust) engine. And should be more efficient.

Theoretical physicists are known for borrowing adjectives from common language to label quantum properties, like the quark flavors strange, charm, top and bottom. No lemon, mint or chocolate. What kind of hard science do you expect here?

Hmm...I agree with @L.Dutch this is stuff at the very very VERY bleeding edge of physics bordering on the impossible, so asking for hard science is kind of a tall order. It is an interesting question, but you should remove the hard-science tag and replace it something more permissive.

If anyone could answer this question definitively and affirmatively to the ruthless expectations of the [tag:hard-science] tag they would be running to the patent office and not answering your question. It would revolutionize transportation. All transportation. I therefore conclude, along with my learned colleagues, that your request for [tag:hard-science] is inappropriate as Antares' answer (which fails [tag:hard-science] and is subject to deletion) is as close to a "yes" as you can get and the only answer that meets the [tag:hard-science] requirements is "no." ... (*Continued*)

... This is a great idea for [tag:science-based], though, but it's asked wrong for that. You need to shift from engineering back to worldbuilding and ask, "how do I rationalize this fabulous idea?"

@JBH: Hey, my answer is as science-hard as can be! ;.)

@Antares Cheers, but what you really mean is, "it's as hard-science as an affirmative answer can be."

I do agree that this shouldn't really be hard-science since the Higgs field is still under active investigation by CERN and others, but I do think it's a conceptually-interesting question.

If I were trying to build one, I'd get a big block of handwavium, and grind it down to a propeller shape.

The answer that you accepted is wrong, and is just spreading misinformation. Please unaccept it. The Higgs field is not viscous. There is no "debate" except people who don't know what they're talking about arguing against people who do.

Pretty sure we don't know nearly enough to give a proper [tag:hard-science] answer to this question, too much is still up for debate.

This is open to debate among scientists.
The Higgs field is nothing tangible. It is considered to be the quantum-level source of that what we experience or explain as "mass", "inertia" or "weight" (and gravity because of the mass) on the macroscopic level.
It does interact with bosons and fermions only if they have a very low state of energy. Thus, the interactions are very short lived, because if a particle gains some mass from the field, it also gains some energy, popping it out of the field interaction again.
If you want to "dip" into the Higgs field and gain some "drive" or momentum from it, you are essentially after the effect of an "impulse drive" from StarTrek (although StarTrek will probably define it working differently; momentum in german is impuls, by the way, therefore "impulse drive" is such a fitting name).
This is kind of defying (known) physics, because you would create a momentum from "nothing". Which contradicts the law of momentum conservation.
However, there are people/scientists who are trying to get this to work (using a piezo-electric approach). Maybe it is possible after all.

The quantum source of about 1% of what we experience or explain as mass. 99% of the mass of the macroscopic bodies around us is simply the mass equivalent of the binding energy of the quarks which make up the protons and neutrons in atomic nuclei. Without the Higgs field I would be maybe 1 kilogram lighter, which I am anyway before eating dinner.

I hadn't thought of Mr. Woodward's Mach Effect engine that way before. But I see that you can. Thank you.

You know, you can also explain the "Mach effect" drive as simply increasing a capacitor's mass, moving it one way, decreasing the mass, and moving it the other way, by way of the electric field's stored mass energy. The whole Mach effect explanation of "distant things affect nearby things" has never been clearly defined, and it's a very eccentric definition of inertia to begin with. Also, despite Woodward's claims about his drive, he's never publicly demonstrated it, and other labs fail to reproduce his supposed results. Just a thought to watch out for.

Also @Antares, the Higgs field is responsible for the masses of the W and Z bosons specifically (as well as some other minor components of fermion mass) - see AlexP's comment.

Gravity is a different field. The word you're looking for is probably inertia

@NoName: I meant gravity, because where mass is, is gravity... but you are right, it is kinda misleading! I'll edit to clarify. Thanks for the feedback!

Probably not
As I and others point out, the Higgs boson contributes mass to the W and Z bosons, not to most fermions in the traditional sense of "mass". Theoretically, if you could design some device that causes the Higgs field to push on the W and Z bosons with which it is coupled, you could gain some impulse from effectively nothing; your Higgsinator would require power obviously, but it wouldn't need propellant if it could play around with the Higgs field that way.
Issue is, the W and Z bosons are the quanta of the weak field and mediate the weak interaction, which is as you might presume very weak. In fact it's more important that it can change quark flavors and lepton types than that it exerts any force at all; excepting gravity, it's the weakest force that we know of. Even if you could amplify it onethousandfold using the Higgsinator by creating a weak-force pressure differential across your vehicle, the resulting acceleration would be on the order of the masses of the W and Z bosons themselves - far too little to justify your multitrillion dollar investment in manipulating one of the most fundamental components of spacetime.
Then again, the Higgs field is still unknown. Maybe it couples to magnetic monopoles or tetraquarks or something in a way we don't understand that would let you work the Higgsinator for meaningful acceleration. We just don't know yet.

The answer is no. I can give you a short and a long  answer.
Short one : The entire standard model has translational symmetry. Therefore, the momentum is conserved q.e.d. So no reaction less engines.
Now for the long answer.
For you to push on the highs field, you need to create disturbances in this field. This is the same thing as a Highs particle. Therefore, your engine would be just firing the Highs particles backwards. This type of engine would be just a less efficient version of the photon engine.
But in  a sense, we are using engines like this everywhere.  Highs filed gives a bit of mass to all particles and, therefore, makes rocket engines give more thrust.
